# What to do when there's a duplicate question that doesn't have answer info you want to add?

Tags: discussion

What are you supposed to do when someone asks a question that is a duplicate of another question, but the previously asked question only has one answer and that one answer does not cover several of the answer options you want to provide?

Here's an example.

Most recently asked question: [Don't lose input type="file" value after page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285524/dont-lose-input-type-file-value-after-page-reload/22285615#22285615)

Former duplicates that include one possible answer, but not the one you want to contribute: [Restoring the value of a input type=file after failed validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205634/restoring-the-value-of-a-input-type-file-after-failed-validation) and [How to retain file input value after form submission with errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858347/how-to-retain-file-input-value-after-form-submission-with-errors)

What I did in this case is add an answer to the new question, refer to one of the previous questions and then add my info to the new answer.

Comment: If the questions are exact duplicates, what's wrong with answering the original question and not the new one?

Comment: @psubsee2003 not "wrong" per se, but answering old, accepted question has very small chance of getting upvotes even if the new answer is the best or most up to date, and even less chance of becoming the accepted answer. Answer is likely to get lost in the noise, being of benefit to few people, etc. So answering an old question could be seen as a waste of time and effort by somebody.

Comment: @hyde - that seems to be the crux of the issue.  It seems to be a bit of a tradeoff between putting an answer on an old question that isn't going to be seen by very many people (including some reading the new question) vs. putting the answer on the "question in play" at the moment that will be seen by a lot more people.  If there were lots of useful answers on the prior question, then it's clear that you add to that older question and mark the newer one as a dup.  But, if the older question only has one, not very comprehensive answer, it seems more up-in-the-air which is the best way to go.

Comment: @hyde - It depends how many views the duplicate gets. Three out of my top four current answers on Stack Overflow were supplied more than two years after the original question. (with [366](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133031/how-to-check-if-column-exists-in-sql-server-table/5369176#5369176), [280](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows/3822833#3822833), [164](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists/11074428#11074428) votes currently)

Comment: @hyde I understand that aspect, but unfortunately that is the whole point of duplicates.  Answering a duplicate question just spreads the answers out over multiple questions and makes it harder for someone coming in via google to find answers.  If we say "just answer the new question so you get more rep", then why bother to have duplicates.

Comment: Posting an answer to a question bumps it to the "active" list and the front page, @hyde, no matter how old it is. More importantly, as much as we all like the little  dopamine squirt from upvotes, if you're _just_ here for the repz, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Rep is also the best available measure of how useful an answer is. So if someone wants to just "make programming world a better place" (and I don't mean this derisively, I do wish that too!), not getting upvotes for an answer still indicates, writing it was not time well spent. Other than that, I don't disagree.

Comment: That's a fair point, @hyde, but a lot of upvotes come [in the long run](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/), from inbound Google links. You can't necessarily judge the answer's overall usefulness even in the first week of its existence. I've got a three-year old answer that gets upvotes in dribs and drabs every month, and another answer to that question, posted a year after mine, seems to do the same.

Comment: @MartinSmith But unless you can attach a new answer with substantial new content to a popular question (a rare opportunity I think), getting that kind of upvotes is unlikely.